# How can i get date from foreach for linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have this two codes.First one create date from today to seven days before except weekends. How can i combine second code to first one. I need to get dates from first code and use it for compare with  m.CreationDate . I will use this code for : get typeid 1 and that days total book number for everydays. Thanks for answer...

```
public static List<DateTime> GetBusinessDays(DateTime startDate, int numDays)
    {
        var dates = new List<DateTime>();

        var step = (numDays < 0) ? -1 : 1;
        var date = startDate;
        var absNumDays = Math.Abs(numDays);

        while (dates.Count() < absNumDays)
        {
            date = date.AddDays(step);

            if (date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                continue;

            dates.Add(date);
        }

        return dates;
    }


string DateString = "";
var start = DateTime.Now;
var Dates = GetBusinessDays(start,-7);
            Dates.Reverse();
foreach (var date in Dates)
{   
    DateString  = DateString + "'" + date.ToShortDateString() + "',";
} 

DateString = DateString.TrimEnd(',');

var book = from m in  Connection.Db.Materials
           where m.TypeId == 1 && m.25.05.2015,.ToShortDateString() == xx//need to write days here but for everyday
           group m by m.TypeId into g
           select new { Count = g.Count()};
```

get data from Dates :18.5.2015, 19.05.2015,20.05.2015,21.05.2015,22.05.2015,25.05.2015,26.05.2015.

I trying to get:   m.CreationDate ==
19.05.2015 and typeid ==1 total book numbers:50

m.CreationDate ==
20.05.2015 and typeid ==1 total book numbers:15

Comment: You want to check if `m.CreationDate` is equals to each of date in your `Dates` collection?

Comment: yes im looking  that and i need everydays total book number( typeid must be 1) like : 25.5.2015 = 20books ,22.5.2015= 15books ,21.5.2015= 50books

Comment: Have you tried grouping by `m.CreationDate`? For example, 

`where m.TypeId == 1
 group m by m.CreationDate into g
           select new { Count = g.Count()};`

After that you get total number of records grouped by creation date.

Comment: yes i tried but i need dates from Dates but i couldnt get it from foreach .

Comment: Ok. You have date collection in `Dates`. Then you perform grouping as `var book = from m in  Connection.Db.Materials
           where m.TypeId == 1 group m by m.CreationDate into g select g`. Then you can do `var result = Dates.Select(d => new { Date = d, Count = book.Where(g => g.Key == d).Count() })`. And in result you get collection dates from `Dates` with count from you second collection.

Comment: Your code work thank you for help   ilyabreev

Comment: I posted this comment as answer. If it really helped you can you accept my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string DateString = "";
var start = DateTime.Now;
var Dates = GetBusinessDays(start,-7);
Dates.Reverse();
foreach (var date in Dates)
{   
   DateString  = DateString + "'" + date.ToShortDateString() + "',";
 } 

DateString = DateString.TrimEnd(',');

var book = from m in Connection.Db.Materials 
           where m.TypeId == 1 
           group m by m.CreationDate into g select g;
           var results = Dates.Select(d => new { Date = d.Day + "/" + d.Month + "/" + d.Year, Count = book.Where(g => g.Key.Day == d.Day && g.Key.Month == d.Month && g.Key.Year == d.Year).Count() }).ToList(); 
//put day, month and year. Because only dates  equals with ohter dates.(I need only dates not times)

string Books = "";
foreach(var r in results)
{
  Books = Books + r.Count + ',';
}
```

Thanks Everbody for Helping

Answer (score 3):

If you toss the dates into a collection then you can use Contains in linq

```
var book = from m in  Connection.Db.Materials
       where m.TypeId == 1 && CreationDatesArray.Contains(m.CreationDate) 
       group m by m.TypeId into g
       select new { Count = g.Count()};
```

Added m. as pointed out

Comment: Shouldn't that be `m.CreationDate`

Answer (score 1):

Ok. You have date collection in `Dates`. 
Then you perform grouping as

```
var book = from m in Connection.Db.Materials 
           where m.TypeId == 1 
           group m by m.CreationDate into g 
           select g
```

Then you can do

```
 var result = Dates.Select(d => new {
    Date = d, 
    Count = book.Where(g => g.Key == d).Count() })
```

And in `result` you get collection of dates from `Dates` with count from your second collection.